# Wait for subprocess .exe to finish before proceeding in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, wait, popen

I'm running an application from within my code, and it rewrites files which I need to read later on in the code. There is no output the goes directly into my program. I can't get my code to wait until the subprocess has finished, it just goes ahead and reads the unchanged files.

I've tried subprocess.Popen.wait(), subprocess.call(), and subprocess.check_call(), but none of them work for my problem. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work? Thanks.

Edit: Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
    os.chdir('C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\FORCAST\dusty')
    t = subprocess.Popen('start dusty.exe', shell=True)
    t.wait()      
    os.chdir('C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\FORCAST')
```

Comment: People normally complain about the opposite; i.e. blocking subprocesses. What does your code look like? (add it to the question)

Comment: Perhaps the application spawns a separate process and returns immediately after doing so.

Comment: How would I know if that is happening, and if it is, how would I resolve it?

Comment: Why do you start the exe in a shell? You can run it directly, can't you?

Comment: @Spuds Do any of these two `subprocess` variations work? http://pastebin.com/raw/0Usu2f36 You can also set the current working directory via `subprocess'` `cwd=/path/to/dir/` option. Sure you need `shell=True`? (it can be a security risk)

Comment: It's not a security risk for this, the .exe it's running is a fortran 90 code that does one thing.

Comment: @Spuds Well... Did you try running the pastebin script?

Comment: The return_val method doesn't do the trick, and the check_output gives me an error:
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Users/Jeremy/Documents/FORCAST/dusty/dusty.exe']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: @Spuds Ok, `non-zero exit status 1` *might* indicate that the Fortran program itself is failing somehow. You seem to have access to the Fortran source code - perhaps you could check what would case it to return 1 rather than 0.

Comment: The code runs properly though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the return object of subprocess.Popen()?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
p.wait()
```

should work.

Are you sure that the command does not end instantly?

Comment: That's what I have now. The command runs, but my code doesn't wait.

Comment: Show your code then please and look at the comment of @martineau to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you execute a program with

```
t = subprocess.Popen(prog, Shell=True)
```

Python won't thrown an error, regardless whether the program exists or not. If you try to start an non-existing program with Popen and Shell=False, you will get an error. My guess would be that your program either doesn't exist in the folder or doesn't execute. Try to execute in the Python IDLE environment with Shell=False and see if you get a new window.